# Найти время подсчета каждого числа Фибоначчи заданного индекса

Tags: java, числа-фибоначчи

Дан рекурсивный алгоритм вычисления чисел Фибоначчи. Задача состоит в том, чтобы найти время подсчета каждого числа Фибоначчи заданного индекса.
После 40 программа начинает виснуть. Как подсчитать время для больших индексов?
(Задача была до 100 посчитать время в секундах, больше 100 или 100 в годах.)

```
public class ulesanne3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            /**
             * open input file
             */
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader 
                    (new FileReader ("./src/kodtoo1/kodtoo1.in"));

            /**
             * open output file
             */
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("./src/kodtoo1/kodtoo1.out");

            /**
            * String , where we write .in information.
            */
            String s;

            /**
            * Read information from input file by lines.
            */
            while((s=in.readLine())!=null){

            /**
             * Convert information from string to int.
             */
            int n = Integer.parseInt(s);

                /**
                 * fib_time algorithm
                 */
                fib_time(n);

                 /**
                 * print result to the file
                 */
                out.println(fib_time(n));
                /**
                 * print result to the console.
                 */
                System.out.println(fib_time(n));

            }   
            /**
             * close in and out file
             */
                in.close();
                out.close();

            }   
            /**
             * exception if we don't find  file kodtoo1.in
             */
            catch (IOException e ){
                System.out.println("No file!"); 
            }

    }

/**
 * fib_time
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
public static String fib_time(int n){
    double timeSpent,start ;

    /**
     * Time starts in nanoseconds 
     */
    start = System.nanoTime();

       fib(n);
    /**
     * delta = end time - start time
     */
    timeSpent =( System.nanoTime() - start);

    String result = "";
    /**
     * if n is smaller than 100 , make time in a seconds
     */
    if (n<100){
        double Time = timeSpent/1000000000;
        result  = "Spent time:" + Time +   "  seconds" ;
    }
    /**
     * if n is bigger than 100 or its 100 , make time in years
     */
    if(n>=100){
        double Time = timeSpent/1000000000;
        result ="Spent time:" + Time +   "  years";
    }

/**
 * Strings
 */

 String index = "index:" +n;
 String fibonacci = "Fibonacci:" + fib(n);
 String total = result +"\n" + index + "\n"+ fibonacci +"\n";

return total;
}

/**
 * fibonacci 
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
public static int fib(int n)
{

    if( n <= 2) return 1;
    else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Известно, что при классическом рекурсивном алгоритме на вычисление числа Фибоначчи f(n) нужно сделать f(n+1) рекурсивных вызовов. Поэтому общее время на вычисление числа Фибоначчи n нужно времени f(n+1) * t, где t - это время на один вызов.

Числа Фибоначчи можно считать приблизительно по [известной формуле](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8)

[image: f(n) = sigma^n / sqrt(5)]

где

[image: sigma]

Если применять вычисление степени через логарифм, то числа будут считаться очень быстро.

Теперь нужно определить коэффициент t. Понятно, что при больших числах один рекурсивный вызов будет дольше, так как складывать 32-битные числа и 1024-битные - "две большие разницы" (с). Поэтому он должен зависеть от n, при чем, скорее всего, линейно.

Для этого запускаем код с вопроса с разными значениями n и смотрим на время. Я тестил на виртуалке, поэтому время может быть маленьким.

```
n    time    f(n)      per request
30 - 0.0057 (832040)   - 6.85 нс
35 - 0.0611 (9227465)  - 6.62 нс
37 - 0.1600 (24157817) - 6.62 нс
39 - 0.4149 (63245986) - 6.56 нс
```

У меня получилось приблизительно одинаковое время. Но это потому, что работаем с 32-битными числами, и процессору побоку. Если будет BigInt, то время должно быть пропорционально размеру числа (скорее всего, график будет не линейный, а ступеньками).

А теперь перейдем собственно к программе. Программа при старте должна проганять число 35-37 и считать время на один вызов (просто разделив). Потом для заданного n считать быстро число Фибоначчи и умножать на полученную константу. Если время будет получаться порядка 2-3 лет, то вряд ли кто-то сможет доказать, что оно "неверно":)

Код мне писать как-то не с руки, так как он очень примитивный. Нужно вычислить значения выражения (да, я поленился упростить выражения)

```
(((1+sqrt(5)) / 2) ^ (n+1)) / sqrt(5) * 6.5e-9
```

Кстати, для 100 получается 3.7 на 10 в 12 степени секунд... это 118 тысяч лет. Для 76 будет чуточку больше года... Долго проверять результат прямым расчетом.

Answer (score 1):

Программа зависает из-за огромного количества рекурсивных вызовов.
При N = 40 происходит 204668309 вызовов функции fib.
При N > 45 число уже превышает знаковое целое (становится отрицательным).

Для больших N будет очень большое время на выполнение рекурсивной функции, естественно все это время программа будет работать ...

В данном случае, по-моему, задачу решать надо через поиск количества итераций вызова функции fib. Замерять время выполнения 1 итерации и перемножать на их количество. Это намного быстрее будет, чем делать рекурсивный подсчет числа.

Но тут появляется еще 1 нюанс, для расчета чисел при N > 90 понадобятся переменные намного выше Int64, а значит надо уже смотреть в сторону BigInteger.

Для себя тоже было интересно подумать над этой задачкой, в математике не особо силен, решил найти закономерность и на ее основе накидать функцию подсчета итераций.

**Delphi:**

```
function fib_count_it(n:integer): int64;
var
  k : integer;
  i1, i2 : int64;
begin
  Result := 0;

  if (n = 1) or (n = 2) then
  begin
    result := 1;
    exit;
  end;

  i1 := 1;
  i2 := 1;

  for k := 3 to n do
  begin
    Result := (i1+i2)+1;
    i1 := i2;
    i2 := Result;
  end;
end;
```

На **Java** проверить не могу, нет инструментов, но накидал примерчик, чтобы хотя бы идея была видна:

```
public static BigInteger fib_count_it (int n)
    {
        if (n == 1 || n == 2) return 1;

        BigInteger i1, i2, i3;
        i1 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        i2 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

        for(int k = 0; k <= n; k++)
        {
            i3 = i1.add(i2) + 1;
            i1 = i2;
            i2 = i3;
        }

        return i3;
    }
```

Суть заключается в том, что для подсчета итерация начиная с числа N = 3 мы берем количество 2 предыдущих итераций + 1, как то так: I(n) = (I(n-2) + I(n-1)) + 1;

З.Ы. Не математик, не ругайте. :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли!)

Answer (score 1):

Каждый вызов функции `Fib`, порождает еще два вызова функции fib. Т.е. по сути мы имеем бинарное дерево вызовов, а значит количество вызовов растет как `2F(n) - 1`.

Из определения функции `Fib` следует, что значения для `Fib(0)` и `Fib(1)` нам известны. Следовательно нужно подсчитать количество узлов дерева, которые выполняют, по сути, элементарные операции, и вычесть их из общего количества узлов дерева.

Остается замерить время одного вызова и умножить на получившееся количество узлов.